# Android debug mode won't start

Tags: android, debugging

I'm having trouble with the debug mode on my phone. I want to try my Android applications on my phone, but each time I connect the phone in debug mode, the phone won't enter debug mode, and my Eclipse won't recognize the device. Do you happen to know what could I know to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you install required drivers for your phone? Did you enable debugging on your phone?

Comment: Yes debugging mode is On, and as for the drivers, do I need any special driver for using debugging mode?

Comment: Are you using Windows or other OS?

Comment: @CarlosT, Some devices are installed automatically, but some aren't. You can try the drivers under the android-sdk/extras/google/usb_driver folder, or search for your device's proprietary driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your device detail [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). And follow the instruction in that page to enable your device for detection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your devices are configured correctly and debugging sometimes works here are some things to consider (I have the problem myself).

1 - Your USB cable is flakey.  A cable that works for charging may still have a missing, loose or damaged wire that impedes or prevents debugging.

2 - Your USB driver/stack on one of the two devices has gotten into a broken mode. Reboot both devices (phone and computer).

3 - Timing glitch (race condition?) in the connection process.  I believe this is the case since I have resolved the problem on OS X be repeatedly plugging and unplugging the device.

4 - Poor connection at the USB plug or our laptop (or the phone).

Comment: Is it possible that wire is damaged in the charging port of the phone itself, so ensuring that the phone can only charge but cannot carry out other USB functions like Media Sharing and Debugging?